# Git push error "You must verify your email address."

Tags: github

When I'm trying to push to GitHub, I get the following error:

```
remote: You must verify your email address.
remote: See https://github.com/settings/emails.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/userRep.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am absolutely sure that my email is already verified.
I've tried to add remote url without .git, but it didn't help.

Comment: if you have readed this thread before the problem was not solved.

Just: "OK, the issue went away by itself this morning with no input from me, no idea why it happened."

Comment: Its 2FA bug, without 2FA it works propely

Answer (score 16):

I faced the same error. I suspect it was due to incorrect credentials cached in git (previously I committed to a private repo using different credentials)

Solved by

```
git push https://username:password@github.com/user/userRep.git
```

After executing this command, `git push` started to work.

Comment: This worked for me, this seems to have overwritten the bad credentials. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How sad that it doesn't work if your password contains exclamation mark (!)

Comment: This will also not work if your password contains @.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered the same issue after changing Github account.

I figure out that it happens because the username and passwords previously used are saved in git credential storage.

Git allows for local storage of credentials, so we don't need to re-enter the username and password each time we request access to Github Repo, and it will automatically go to the specified folder ( .gitconfig )to find the credentials.

> On macOSX:
>
> Homebrew preset Git to use `osxkeychain` to storage credentials.
>   Every time we send out `git push` command ( When access Github over HTTPS ), Git will use the username
>   and password that `osxkeychain` saved to ask Github Repo for
>   accessing.
>
> This is WHY git push fatal and keep asking to verify email.

Use  `git config --show-origin --get credential.helper`
could find out where *.gitconfig* file is.

Then you will need to modify this line in *.gitconfig*  : 
`[credential]   helper = osxkeychain`.

`helper = xxxx` decides the way that credentials storage.

In my case, I had deleted `[credential]   helper = osxkeychain` and saved the file. 
So that git would ask for username and passwords while `Git push`.

After entering new username and password, `git push` works successfully.

Then I change setting back by :

```
git  config --global  credential.helper  osxkeychain
```

Or you could add `[credential]   helper = osxkeychain` back in .gitconfig.

Hope my exeperience could help someone.

Comment: Excellent well document fix. I didn't actually need to run the second call. Just needed to delete the gitconfig file. Looked like updating to new xcode 10.2 did some strange things... All works now, thank you for sharing.

Comment: Found gitconfig file in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-core/
Just deleted that file & git asked to login again. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Your can set github url with who you are —— username and password

```
 git remote set-url origin  https://YourName:YourPassword@github.com/YourName/YourRepo.git
```

I encountered the same issue after changing Github account.

---

And in earth, you'll need to remove authorization info from Keychain.

[image: one]

In my case, there are many github accounts in keychain.

Comment: I just removed my github credentials from Keychain and git asked me for them again, when I pushed code - and everything worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I was experiencing this issue on osx (and my email address was verified), the following command solved it for me:

```
ssh-add -D && ssh-add
```

Answer (score 1):

*I tried all these, but **neither worked**:*

- my email address was already verified,
- checked `git config user.email` to make sure it is correct
- also checked `git config user.email` and it was all good
- tried removing my ssh key and generating a new one and adding it to the ssh-agent and github
- checked `ssh -T git@github.com` to make sure it is authorised
- did `ssh-add -d` to remove any added key, generated a new key and added to ssh-agent and github
- checked the config file by doing `cat ~/.ssh/config` to make sure there is no invalid username there

What ***worked*** was very simple: **restarting my machine**

Hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not using a SSH key, but username/password authenticaton.

For Windows:

Open Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Credential Manager

Delete GitHub entry

Try again. A window will appear asking for your email/password. Enter your proper credentials.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I generated the SSH key using *ed25519* instead of *rsa*. Switching to *rsa* fixed the problem immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You cloned repo as https (by default in github interface) and trying to push it through a git protocol.
Open .git/config and change `url` from `https` to `url = git@github.com:...`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened when I changed my Github password but on my Mac Keychain Access program, the stored password was still the old one. After updating the password in Keychain Access, the git push command worked again.

If you suspect this might be your case, just open Keychain Access on Mac, search for `github`, and update the password for all relevant entries.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I'd recently changed my git auth from HTTPS to SSH. I was trying to push using SSH, but Git kept trying the credentials from the keychain.

Based on the solution from jinny-chen, here's what made the trick for me:

- `vim ~/.gitconfig`. *You can find your config file with `git config --show-origin --get credential.helper`*
- Remove the helper credential to tell git to stop using user/pass creds

```
[credential]
   helper = osxkeychain
```

- `git push --set-upstream origin master`

Answer (score -1):

I verified my email once. When it says `You must verify your email address`, I verify my email again and problem solve.

Answer (score -1):

I just checked my repository and saw a message from github.

[image: This is what I saw]

Now click on verify email and it will send an email and you are all set. It worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/settings/emails to verify your emails,click resend button ,then login your email and click the mail from github to you.
that perfect !