# Unable to push to Git - keeps asking me to verify email

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push a commit to this repo: 
https://github.com/ttchuah/react-csv.git/

I keep getting this error:
remote: You must verify your email address.
remote: See https://github.com/settings/emails.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ttchuah/react-csv.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

My email address *has* been verified but I keep getting this error. Anything I may be missing here?

---

NOTE: I run "git config --get user.email" and the email is the same as I one I just verified.

I am able to push to GitHub from other repos on my machine without issue.

This is a fork of someone else's repo, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Did you change your OS or did some thing like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing as a workaround: 
`git push https://ttchuah:password@github.com/ttchuah/react-csv.git`

Thanks to NoobTW for leading me down this route.

Comment: It won't work if your password contains @.

Answer (score 1):

What's your git's `user.email`? Does it match your GitHub account email?

Use `git config --global user.email` to check your global git configuration or use `git config user.email` to check your repository configuration.

If it doesn't match, use `git config --global user.email "hi@example.com"` to set your email.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes my user.email *does* match my GitHub account email. (See notes in my updated question, which I posted just a split second after your answer)

Comment: If you clone that repo again on the same machine, can you push it?

Comment: Nope. Tried cloning to a different location on my machine but it didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660326/git-push-error-you-must-verify-your-email-address

Comment: Ok, that does work. Thank you. For anyone who's reading, I ran this command: git push https://ttchuah:password@github.com/ttchuah/react-csv.git

Comment: I'd welcome a more permanent solution from anyone else. :) It'd be nice to not have to run that command every time I want to do a git push.

Comment: idk why, I can push without problem after forking and cloning this repo.

Comment: Did you use git on ssh protocol or https protocol? Although both works for me.

Comment: https I think. Anyways, I can live with this for now, I'll upvote your answer for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and it is because that I changed Github account. So that the username and passwords previously saved in Git credential storage weren't correct.

Maybe you could check what kinds of ways that **git storage credentials** on your computer operating system:

```
git help -a | grep credential
```

In my case, I use macOSX, when git access Github Repo over HTTPS it preset to use **osxkeychain** to deliever username and passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Jinny!

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
```

and

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

use this command for verify user.